# Google App Engine error "Upstream sent too big header"

Tags: google-app-engine, nginx, google-app-engine-php

I am running a Laravel app with Google App Engine Standard PHP 7.2, with Elfinder package.

Today, I receive 502 error while trying to access Elfinder. Upon analyzing the log, I found this particular error:

> 96 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: , request: "GET /xxx/elfinder/connector?_token=XXX", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/google-config/php-fpm.sock:", host: "XXX", referrer: "XXX".

After googling for similar problem, I found out it is probably a problem with nginx proxy_buffer_size. However, I did not know how to edit nginx.conf in Google App Engine Standard. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue on GAE standard php73 and this probaby has to do with the app.yaml

```
    SESSION_DRIVER:     cookie
```

setting (or in your .env)
This sends all session info via the header, and this can become too big (dont know the GAE default limit)

You will need to use a redis (GCS memorystore) or database setting for the session. GCS memorystore was too expensive ($33 per month minimum) for me so I use the database as session driver.

Comment: Yep. Definitely. I've found the solution but forget to post the solution here.

Basically, when session is saved in cookie, the header will sent a session cookie, which is too long to be buffered by App Engine's default nginx setup.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I was about to change from standard to flex in App Engine, instead this simple solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

You dont' have a nginx.conf file in App Engine Standard so that's why you can't edit or customize it.

You have a nginx.conf file in App Engine Flexible environment.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/quickstart) is the Official Google Cloud Platform Documentation to create an App Engine Flexible environment, and [customize the nginx.conf file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/runtime#customizing_nginx).

After creating a Google App Engine Flexible environment, if you still get the "Upstream sent too big header" error, it's due to that App Engine Flexible is using the default proxy_buffer_size which is 4K and you need more.

So you can put the following code in you nginx.conf file:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Tried migrating to flexible env and override the proxy_buffer_size, but no luck. Problem still persist. Do you know how I can take a look at the content of upstream header response which caused the problem? I think I should start with that now.